# battery dies while truck not running

Tags: battery

2001 chev pick up battery drains while not running. Can park at night and turn everything off. When I try to start it in morning battery is dead

Answer (score 3):

First try this:

1. Park the car and disconnect the battery.
2. Wait (and sleep).
3. Next morning: Reconnect the battery.

If it is dead then you got a problem with the battery. If not you have something which drains it overnight. Which leads to the next step: Finding out which part causes the drain.

To do this either disconnect some of the fuses during the night until the drain stops.
Or put something in between the battery and the car and measure the current flow. (e.g. a lamp, or a multimeter).

WARNING: Do not try to start the car or use the headlights in the latter case. Those will draw a lot of current and you will need a new multimeter.

Answer (score 2):

All sorts of things can cause this, but they all come down to current draw. Something is drawing power from your battery. It could be as simple as lights or the stereo being left on.

Even interior lights will drain a battery.

So your first check should be simple.

If you are certain there is nothing on, your next step should be to check for unwanted current flow; short circuits, dodgy wiring etc. - and this is best done by a qualified electrician.